# test class for wrapper class in apex

Tags: apex, code-coverage, apextestrunresult

```
  public with sharing class ResponseWrapper{
    public String Id;
    public String Time; 
    public String lobType;
    public String businessContextId;
    public Information[] document;

    public class Information{
    public String id;  
    public String type;
    public String context;
    public ErrorInformation[] errors;
    public Data data;
  }

  public class ErrorInformation{
    public String code;  
    public String description;  
  }

  public class Data Data {
    public PersonDetail[] person;
  }

  public class PersonDetail{
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public Integer age;
    public String gender;  
  }
```

above is my wrapper class i want to write a test class for the same, as my wrapper class don't have any method/constructor the covering lines are coming 0%
so for writting test class for this i have created a method that is returing instance of this class is this approach is fine, or i should try something else?

```
 public with sharing class ResponseWrapper{
    public String Id;
    public String Time; 
    public String lobType;
    public String businessContextId;
    public Information[] document;

    public class Information{
    public String id;  
    public String type;
    public String context;
    public ErrorInformation[] errors;
    public Data data;
  }

 public class ErrorInformation{
    public String code;  
    public String description;  
 }

 public class Data Data {
    public PersonDetail[] person;
 }

 public class PersonDetail{
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public Integer age;
    public String gender;  
 }

 public static ResponseWrapper getInstance(){
    return new ResponseWrapper();     
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class is not covered because it contains no executable lines of code. There is nothing to cover.

It is not necessary to add a constructor for the purpose of simulating coverage. Code coverage is defined as a percentage is *executable* lives covered, so your wrapper class requires no test class and does not impact your org's coverage.